# Robot leg passing through the ground

Tags: game-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I have modeled a simple robot leg. There is a U shaped socket at the top. A cylinder is attached in this U shape. The cylinder is the child of U socket. I rotate U socket via arrow keys using logic bricks to move the cylinder (U socket acts like a motor).
The problem is that when I rotate the leg, it passes through the ground.

U Shaped Socket - Dynamic
Cylinder - Dynamic, Box Collision
Ground - Plane, Static, Triangle Mesh

Why is this happening? How do I prevent the leg from passing through the ground?

**Update**
Please find the .blend file here.
[image]

Comment: Animations are ... just animations. It passes through the ground, because you animate it that way. Remember a game is pure illusion. If you want it to  act like it does not pass the ground, you need to adjust you animation accordingly. Typically you create a walk cycle that assumes a flat (but small ground). This way the passing (e.g. on slopes)  is minor enough to appear acceptable. Otherwise you need different animations for different situations.

Comment: The technique you are looking for is automated ground detection. You wanna use the *Floor constraint* on bones and also some socripting.